# onMessage props not calling in React Native webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

Hello friends i integrate webview in react native app and below is my code

```
 render() {


const injectedJs = `

var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]");

  elements[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.postMessage("Button1");
  });

  elements[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.postMessage("Button2");
  });


`;

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
                source={{ uri: this.state.authURL }}
                bounces={true}
                style={{flex: 1}}
                injectedJavaScript={injectedJs}
                startInLoadingState
                scalesPageToFit
                javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                onNavigationStateChange={this.handleNavigationStateChange}
                onMessage={event => {
                    console.log("MESSAGE IN ONMESSAGE" + event.nativeEvent.data);


                }}
                onLoadStart={() => {
                    console.log("LOAD START ");
                }}
                onLoadEnd={() => {
                    console.log('LOAD END');
                }}
                onError={err => {
                    console.log('ERROR ');
                    console.log(err);
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

When i run above code i have one webview and inside that two button like Button1 and Button2. When i click Button1 in should be print in onMessage event in webview but it is not print right now so any idea how can i solve this?

Comment: Are you getting this error: "Setting onMessage on a WebView overrides existing values of window.postMessage, but a previous value was defined." ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting error : "Setting onMessage on a WebView overrides existing values of window.postMessage, but a previous value was defined."

Then the solution is to add the following code in your injectedJs.

```
      var originalPostMessage = window.postMessage;
      var patchedPostMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer) {
        originalPostMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);
      };

      patchedPostMessage.toString = function() {
        return String(Object.hasOwnProperty).replace('hasOwnProperty', 'postMessage');
      };

      window.postMessage = patchedPostMessage;
```